# How Jasperreports Server stores report output internally?

Tags: jasperserver

There are few ways to store report output in JR Server: FS, FTP and Repository. The repository output is the default one. I guess the files in the repository must be stored in the DB or file system. Are the files kept forever? How can I manage the repository and for example set a file's lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of JasperReports Server v 6.3.0 the reference to all resources is kept in jiresource table, while content of is kept in jiresource.

In my case I was able to retrieve all output reports with:

```
select r.id,r.name,r.creation_date 
from jiresource r, jicontentresource c 
where r.id = c.id;
```

The definition of jicontentresource is

```
jasperserver=# \d+ jicontentresource
 id        | bigint                | not null  | plain    |              |
 data      | bytea                 |           | extended |              |
 file_type | character varying(20) |           | extended |              |
```

Answer (score 0):

The repository outputs are stored in the database. Usually there is no need to set the lifetime.